# Is a large MTLTexture more performant than using multiple smaller MTLTextures?

Tags: macos, graphics, metal, metalkit

I'm using Metal to display an image into a 2D plane. The image is being rendered as tiles to an IOSurface using Core Image. After each tile is rendered, the IOSurface is sent via XPC to the app, wrapped in an `MTLTexture` and its contents are copied to a master texture using a blit encoder. The IOSurface is then re-used if need-be.

I have full control over the tile sizes and texture sizes and I'm wondering if Metal prefers having a small number of large textures, a large number of small textures or if it just doesn't really matter.

There are some tradeoffs that I've already come across and the most notable one is that if I use smaller textures then the cost to (re)generate the mipmaps can be smaller. There's also the issue of textures having a maximum size of 16384, which implies that any image larger than that needs to be tiled anyways.

Consider the following:

*Image dimensions used below are just for easy math, in real life I'm working with DSLR images, panoramas, stitched images, etc..*

**#1 - A single texture that covers the entire image:**

[image: Single Tile]

```
Texture Type: MTLTextureType2D
Texture Size: 400 x 300 px
```

When Core Image renders a tile and I copy it into the texture, I have to regenerate the mipmaps for the entire texture, even though most of the texture's content did not change.

---

**#2 - Using two textures:**

[image: Two Tiles]

```
Texture Type: MTLTextureType2DArray
Texture Array Count: 2
Texture Size: 200 x 300 px (x2)
```

With two tiles covering the image's content, I only have to regenerate the mipmaps for the "dirty" tile.

---

**#3 - Using many textures:**

[image: Many Tiles]

```
Texture Type: MTLTextureType2DArray
Texture Array Length: 12
Texture Size: 100 x 100 px (x12)
```

In this scenario, I can minimize mipmap generation by matching the texture tile size to my rendering tile size, but it will require a large number of `MTLTextures`.

---

`MTLTextureDescriptor.arrayLength` is documented as being able to hold values between 1..2048, which suggests to me that using a large number of textures isn't such a bad thing.

A single texture is passed to my fragment shader and all it does is sample the color at the appropriate coordinates.

Using smaller-sized textures gives me a lot more fidelity in marking the "dirty" regions of the image that need invalidating, but I'm curious if the large number of textures is to be avoided or not.

My current attempts at measuring the performance are somewhat inclusive to me and I wonder if that's because this doesn't matter at all from Metal's perspective. Ultimately, the same amount of memory is needed (from my perspective) but I'd be interested to know if there are performance trade-offs I'm not aware of.

Comment: I would guess that textures are allocated in units of pages (4KB). There's likely to be some wasted at the end of each texture's allocation, because the texture's storage is probably not an exact multiple of a page. So, the more textures, the more waste. But it's probably not a big deal as a percentage of the overall memory use, unless your tiles get to be tiny. You could probably use `MTLHeap` to alleviate even that.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that Apple uses `MTLHeap` even for static textures in some of their sample code. Since the textures all have to be the same size in a `2DArray`, I also get some "unused" space in each texture as the texture size is rarely an even multiple of the image size. Smaller textures minimize that overflow. Memory overhead is important, but probably not a big deal since I'm only loading a single image. I'm most interested in performance implications because when I do a GPU capture in Xcode, I tend to see "Memory Bandwidth Bound" as a performance concern.

Comment: I don't think you are going to see any performance impact with this approach, Metal allocates its own internal buffers that the input textures are read into on the GPU (tiles), so you are unlikely to have any impact on that performance by passing smaller input textures.